# Cast base class object to derived class

Tags: c++, casting

Lets say I have two classes, animal and dog like this.

```
class Animal
{

};

class Dog : public Animal
{

};
```

And I have an animal object named animal, that is actually an instance of dog, how would I cast it back to dog? This may seem like an odd question, but I need it because I am writing a programming language interpreter, and on the stack everything is stored as a BaseObject, and all the other datatypes extend BaseObject.  How would I cast the base object from the stack, to a specific data type?  I have tried something like this

```
Dog dog = static_cast<Dog>(animal);
```

But it gives me an error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: StackTests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  StackTests.cpp
1>c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\stacktests\stacktests\stacktests.cpp(173): error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'Animal' to 'Dog'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\stacktests\stacktests\stacktests.cpp(173): error C2512: 'Dog' : no appropriate default constructor available
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Edit: I have decided to use pointers instead.

Comment: "...how would i cast it back to dog?" : You wouldn't. As-shown these are entirely unrelated types. **Edit**: thank you for making the code match the question.

Comment: im sorry i had a typo, dog extends animal, i have updated my code

Comment: And if this design made any sense at all, then `Animal` would be an abstract class, so you could never ever have an "animal object", and the entire problem goes away.

Comment: i still cant get it to work

Comment: but class animal doesnt have any members, it only exists so that all other derived classes can be stored in the same stack

Comment: So could you show how you're going to try casting, please?? What you are looking for is called [downcasting](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php) (also see [`dynamic_cast<>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast))

Comment: If all else fails use `(Dog*)`.

Comment: (A big part of the problem is that "cast" means two (or maybe 2.5) entirely different things.  When you do `(double)5` you're doing a data conversion operation -- the bits are actually manipulated.  When you do `(Dog*)animalPtr` you are doing a type assertion operation -- informing the compiler that a given pointer is "backed up" by a specific actual type.  Nothing is manipulated beyond the compiler symbol table.  (The 0.5 case is when casting is used for "boxing".))

Comment: @HotLicks: that's not strictly true. There are cases where casting a pointer to a pointer-to-base or pointer-to-derived type does manipulate the bits of the pointer, so pointer conversions aren't so different from numeric conversions as you say. But in a sensible C++ implementation, single non-virtual inheritance is not one of those cases.

Comment: @Popgalop: just to check, your stack doesn't have something like a `vector<Animal>`, does it? Because if so then you're way off course. In C++ you *cannot* store a `Dog` value in an `Animal` object merely because `Animal` is a base class of `Dog`. At best you can store a copy of just the base class part of the original `Dog`. This partial copying is called "slicing", and it is what `static_cast<Animal>(Dog)` does. There is no way to reverse the process (`any_kind_of_cast<Dog>(Animal)`) because the doggishness was lost in the slice. Instead you need to use pointers or references.

Comment: @SteveJessop - This is true only on machines that use byte-addressing pointers for some things and halfword/word/doubleword for others -- a very unusual case anymore.

Comment: @HotLicks: http://ideone.com/nOO1mV gives an example of a cast from pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base, that changes the bits. It does not merely manipulate the compiler symbol table. http://ideone.com/XikbIP is the same result with C-style casts.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Yeah, that's casting a multiple-inheritance object.  Probably flavor 4 of cast.

Comment: @HotLicks: Right, so your classification of conversions is incomplete and hence very misleading. While it is true that there are some conversions which don't change the bits (for example, `(float)(0)` in any implementation that uses IEEE representation and where `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)`), making a special case of them just causes confusion. In this case a cast to `Dog*` wouldn't change the representation, but it's really not important, the issue would be the same whether `Dog` has multiple bases or just the one.

Comment: My point was more that representation *changing* casts (such as float->int) are a distinct category from class-changing casts (Animal->Dog).  In the latter case no change of the actual data occurs (though some implementations may conceivably twiddle the address in some fashion)

Comment: @HotLicks: if you mean what I think you mean, then I believe a better way to state it would be that converting pointers does not modify the referands of those pointers. No need to talk about whether the bits of the pointer change or not. If you mean what you actually typed, then I don't think it makes sense, because the conversion Animal->Dog isn't possible in the questioner's code (as indicated by the error message in the question). And if it did exist then it would construct a `Dog` object from an `Animal` object

Comment: That's kinda my point.  float<->int can go either way (with some losses), but you can (legitimately) convert an Animal pointer to a Dog only if the Animal already is a Dog.  One is changing the form, the other is just changing the applied description.

Comment: @HotLicks: I think you're obscuring the issue by conflating converting pointers with converting user-defined classes. I know *you* know which one you mean in each case, but if you talk about one when you mean the other, then a novice will lose track. You don't convert an Animal pointer to a Dog unless Dog has an `Animal*` constructor. Generally speaking converting a pointer *might* change the form of the thing you're converting, which is a pointer, which is neither an Animal nor a Dog. So it *is* changing the form (of the pointer).

Comment: ... converting a pointer isn't changing the form of any `Animal`, it's true, but that's not because it's a special kind of conversion, it's because the Animal is not the thing it's converting. Of course strictly speaking conversions don't usually *change* anything: they create an output from an input and typically don't modify the input at all. The exception to that rule would be move constructors and suchlike. In case it isn't clear to any reader, what we've meant by "change" throughout this discussion is whether or not the output is bitwise identical to the input.

Comment: My point is that it's largely an accident of history that these divergent concepts are called "cast" and have historically used the same notation.  And that accident leads to a lot of misunderstandings.

Comment: @HotLicks: my point is that you are mistaken to believe that, and that this belief is the cause of misunderstandings :-) A cast is an explicit conversion from one type to another. `Animal*` is a type. `Dog*` is a type. `Animal` is a type. `Dog` is a type. Explicit conversion from any one of those to any other therefore is a cast. Failing to understand the difference between a pointer and the thing pointed to is a common error, sure, but it cannot be solved by learning a taxonomy of casts (or of conversions), it must be solved by learning the difference between a pointer and its referand.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Yes and no.  In Java the distinction is even more muddled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic_cast:

```
Animal& animal = getAnimalFromStack();    
if(Dog *d = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(&animal)) 
    {
       // You have a dog pointer, use *d ...

    }
```

Comment: i get 'Animal' is not a polymorphic type

Comment: Animal needs to have at least one virtual method